# avoid the virtual keyboard popup

Tags: android, android-edittext

I create a EditText and I want to avoid the virtual keyboard pupup when long press the EditText. but still can select the word in the text.

I want to have a EditText which look like textView(already done), and can select the word in the editText for searching. but don't want the virtual keyboard and contextmenu(or change the menu item of it, but it is not important). Can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your own EditText which extends `EditText`, and then override `onCheckIsTextEditor()`:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {
    public MyEditText (Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyEditText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }      

    public MyEditText (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: if I create my own editText MyEditText, can I just use <MyEditText> as a tag  in xml file simply.

Comment: thank you, but I also want the EditText can be select, can I do it?

Comment: you can select / copy / cut / paste as usual

Comment: if I copy your code, I cannot do it. Do I need to modify your code? and how?

Comment: but the keyboard will pop up when long press the edittext after edit the code.

Comment: oh... it works fine for me. I've just got a context menu for select / copy when I long press the EditText...

Comment: ok, i found it is the problem of my tablet zoom. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can set below code for `EditText` in your Code.By this way it will not pop-up Soft-keyboard in android

```
    mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    mEditText.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it -

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```